# Extra output none while printing an command line argument

Tags: python, function

It's my day 1 of learning python. so it's a noob question for many of you. See the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def hello(name):
    name = name + '!!!!'
    print 'hello', name

def main():
    print hello(sys.argv[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I run it

```
$ ./Python-1.py alice
hello alice!!!!
None
```

Now, I have trouble understanding where this `"None"` came from?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Count the number of `print` statements in your code. You'll see that you're printing `"hello alice!!!"` in the `hello` function, *and* printing the result of the `hello` function. Because the `hello` function doesn't return a value (which you'd do with the `return` statement), it ends up returning the object `None`. Your `print` inside the `main` function ends up printing `None`.

Answer (score 6):

Change your

```
def main():
    print hello(sys.argv[1])
```

to

```
def main():
    hello(sys.argv[1])
```

You are explicitly printing the return value from your hello method. Since you do not have a return value specified, it returns `None` which is what you see in the output.