# Why does this code return none

Tags: python, python-3.x

why does the following code returns none:

```
j = 22
def test(j):
    if j > 0:
        print('j>0')
    else:
        print('j<0')
```

Output:

```
j>0
None
```

Comment: And how are you getting that output? Any function will `return None` if no other value is returned

Comment: I am just getting an extra None below my expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function in Python always has a return value, even if you do not use a return statement, defaulting to `None`

Because the `test` function doesn't return a value, it ends up returning the object `None`. that's why it ended up printing `None` Since you do not have a return value specified

you may `not use print` in your function, but return a string instead

```
def test(j):
    if j > 0:
        return 'j>0'
    else:
        return 'j<0'
```

then call it like this: print it when calling the function

```
print(test(22))
```

[see answer's here for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953233/extra-output-none-while-printing-an-command-line-argument)